# Inertia - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')

Tags: laravel, vue.js, server-side-rendering, inertiajs

I'm new to `Inertia`, I want to render a `Vue` component using `Inertia` server side rendering, I have my `UserController.php` as `resource` controller, in my `index` method i render `Index.vue` component:

**UserController.js**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Inertia\Inertia;
use Inertia\Response;
class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function index() : Response
    {
        return Inertia::render('Users/Index',[
            'users' => User::all()
        ]);
    }
...
}
```

just a simple `Vue` component that says "Index Page"

**resources/js/Pages/Users/Index.vue**

```
<script setup></script>

<template>
    <h1>Index Page</h1>
</template>
```

but i'm getting error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')`

Here is my `Inertia` setup
**resources/js/app.js**

```
import "./bootstrap";
import { createApp, h } from "vue";
import { createInertiaApp } from "@inertiajs/vue3";

createInertiaApp({
    resolve: (name) => {
        const pages = import.meta.glob("./Pages/**/*.vue", { eager: true });
        return pages[`./Pages/${name}.vue`];
    },
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .mount(el);
    },
});
```

Comment: resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),          please check if this works

Comment: it didn't work, but i solved the issue

Comment: great, what was that ?

Comment: i have no idea, i tried your code it didn't work, i ```ctrl + z``` and then saved, it worked, mashallah